# error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: http, request, typescript, promise, angular

I'm new to Typescript and Angular2 and I'm trying to create promise on http get request but code below (exactly `return this.http.get(url)` line gives me error:

`error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

In my service I have method `isLoggedIn`

```
isLoggedIn(): Promise<Object> {
    return this.http.get('/some/path')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .toPromise();
}
```

Then I want to use it in my component, like this:

```
onInit() {
    this.login.isLoggedIn()
    .then((data: any) => {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('status') && data.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/Home'])
        }
    });
}
```

I was looking how to use http request and promise the right way but I couldn't find any good description.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at Angular source:

`static toPromise(obj: Observable<any>): Promise<any> { return (<any>obj).toPromise(); }`

Reveals that `toPromise` method should receive an `Observable<any>` (your call was: `toPromise()`)

I guess that this is the reason for the error

Comment: so I should put parameter into toPromise() method but actually I don't have clue what I should put there after http.get request. Documentation for A2 is very poor for now :/ and I'm digging through internet to find a solution

Comment: I will look for this as well. Why don't you stick to Observables?